# Checkbox checker JavaScript does not work. Escape?

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, escaping

In my form, my checkbox elements' name are `onSite[]`.

I've made a simple JavaScript to check them with one click.

```
function checkAll(field)
{
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
    field[i].checked = true ;
}
```

And in the HTML a button which calls the function.

```
<input type="button" name="CheckAll" value="All" onClick="checkAll(document.sharepage.onSite[])">
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work because I'm making array of the checked elements, and the `[]` confuse my JS.
Do you know any solution to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/) when you need to access a property which has a name that includes special characters.

```
document.forms.sharepage.elements['onSite[]']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try separating the onclick handler from HTML.

```
document.getElementById("bt1").onclick = function(){
  CheckAll();
};

function CheckAll()
{
  var elems = document.forms.sharepage.elements['onSite[]'];
  var len = elems.length;

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    elems[i].checked = true;
  }
}
```

​

Comment: Changing to the unobtrusive approach doesn't address the OP's problem and has a major downside in this instance: if you were to, for example, attach this click handler after the document has loaded, which is a common scenario, the user may be able to click on the button before the event handler has been attached and hence not experience the desired behaviour.